# Title case in Angular to not capitalize after apostrophe

Tags: javascript, angular

The default Angular Titlecase pipe capitalizes words after apostrophes. How can that be solved? Also how to selectively not capitalize some words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a custom pipe to take care of that.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'customTitleCase'
})
export class CustomTitleCasePipe implements PipeTransform {


  transform(value: string, args?: any): any {
    if (!value) return null;

    let words = value.split(" ");
    for (var index = 0; index < words.length; index++) {
      var word = words[index];
      if (index > 0 && this.isPreposition(word)) {
        words[index] = word.toLowerCase();
      }
      else {
        words[index] = this.toTitleCase(word);
      }
    }
    return words.join(" ");

  }

  private toTitleCase(word: string): string {
    return word.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  }

  private isPreposition(word: string): boolean {
    let lowerCaseWords = ["a","an","of", "the"]; // add more words to exclude here

    return lowerCaseWords.includes(word.toLowerCase());

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Here is the similar one that can also accept prepositions dynamically from the component

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'customTitleCase'
})
export class CustomTitleCase implements PipeTransform{
    except:string[] = []; 
    transform(value: string, ...except: string[]){ // accepts any number of arguments
        this.except = [...except];
        console.log(this.except);
        if(!value) return null;

        let words = value.split(" ");
        for (var index = 0; index < words.length; index++) {
        var word = words[index];
        if (index > 0 && this.isPreposition(word)) {
            words[index] = word.toLowerCase();
        }
        else {
            words[index] = this.toTitleCase(word);
        }
        }

        return words.join(" ");
    }
    private isPreposition = (word: string):boolean => {
        let lowerCaseWords  = [...this.except];   
        console.log(lowerCaseWords); 
        return lowerCaseWords.includes(word.toLowerCase());
    }

    private toTitleCase = (word: string):string => 
         word.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase();

}
```

---

```
   @Component({
    selector: 'inputTitleCase',
    template: `
            <input [(ngModel)] = "text"/>
            <h4>{{text | customTitleCase:'of':'the' }}</h4> <!--only strings to be passed  -->
        `
})

export class inputTitleCase {
    text = "";
}
```

---

[This is how the result looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMnRg.png)